# How to activate a specifically named virtualenv using pipenv?

Tags: python, pipenv

I created a specifically named virtualenv by setting `PIPENV_CUSTOM_VENV_NAME` before doing `pipenv shell` as outlined [in this Github issue thread on "How to set the full name of the virtualenv created"](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1226).

I can confirm a virtualenv with the name given exists in `/Users/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/`.

Now, how do I activate this specific virtualenv again? Doing `pipenv shell` in the project directory simply creates a new one, so how do I activate the one with a given name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to always export that `PIPENV_CUSTOM_VENV_NAME` environment variable.

It's the same as what that contributor did in [that Github issue thread](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1226#issuecomment-1058248550):

> ```
> export PIPENV_CUSTOM_VENV_NAME=mycustomname  
> pipenv install  
> pipenv shell  
> etc. etc.
> ```

The `export` link sets that environment variable for all subsequent pipenv commands, and this includes activation of the environment:

```
# There is no virtual env yet
# ---

myapp$ PIPENV_CUSTOM_VENV_NAME=foo python3.8 -m pipenv --venv
No virtualenv has been created for this project(/path/to/myapp) yet!
Aborted!

# Let's create one named `foo` !
# ---

myapp$ PIPENV_CUSTOM_VENV_NAME=foo python3.8 -m pipenv install
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /path/to/myapp/Pipfile
Using /usr/local/bin/python3 (3.10.8) to create virtualenv...
⠹ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment 
...

Virtualenv location: /path/to/.venvs/foo

# There is now a virtual env !
# ---

myapp$ PIPENV_CUSTOM_VENV_NAME=foo python3.8 -m pipenv --venv
/path/to/.venvs/foo

# Let's activate it !
# ---

myapp$ PIPENV_CUSTOM_VENV_NAME=foo python3.8 -m pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
myapp$  . /path/to/.venvs/foo/bin/activate
(myapp) myapp$

# Let's check if it's really installing packages in the right place...
# ---

(myapp) myapp$ pipenv install flask
...
(myapp) myapp$ find ~/.venvs/foo/lib/python3.10/site-packages -name flask
/path/to/.venvs/foo/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask
```

Now, this is a bit inconvenient. But you can define it per project in your `.env` file, as per the docs https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#virtual-environment-name

> The logical place to specify this would be in a user’s .env file in the root of the project, which gets loaded by pipenv when it is invoked.

So, in your project, create a .env file, and define it there:

```
myapp$ cat .env
PIPENV_CUSTOM_VENV_NAME=foo
```

So now every time you run `pipenv shell` *in that folder*, pipenv would read your .env file *in that same folder*, and apply `PIPENV_CUSTOM_VENV_NAME`:

```
myapp$ cat .env
PIPENV_CUSTOM_VENV_NAME=foo

myapp$ python3.10 -m pipenv shell
Loading .env environment variables...
Loading .env environment variables...
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
myapp$  . /path/to/.venvs/foo/bin/activate
```

Comment: in addition to above, if you want the custom folder in a different directory, set WORKON_HOME